# Error when trying to use grunt-contrib-uglify: "src files were empty"

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have the following `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var config = {
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    
    /* Some other tasks... */
    
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      def: {
        files: {
          'out/src.js': 'out/src.min.js'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  grunt.initConfig(config);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [/* <other-tasks>, */ 'uglify:def']);
};
```

Folder structure is as follows:

```
project
  |
  +-out (folder)
  +-Gruntfile.js
```

Important: **I run `grunt` from the `project` folder**.

When running `grunt`, there is a task before `uglify:def` which is responsible for generating `src.js` into `project/out`.

When I run `grunt` I can see `src.js` being generated into `project/out`, but when Grunt runs `uglisy:def` I get the following error:

> Running "uglify:def" (uglify) task.
>
> Destination out/src.js not written because src files were empty.
>
> No files created.

What am i doing wrong?

#### Log

When running with `--verbose` I get:

```
Running "uglify:def" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.def exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> out/src.js
Options: banner="/*! My Pack 2015-07-19 */\r\n", footer="", compress={"warnings":false}, mangle={}, beautify=false, report="
min", expression=false, maxLineLen=32000, ASCIIOnly=false, screwIE8=false, quoteStyle=0
>> Destination out/src.js not written because src files were empty.
>> No files created.
```

Comment: Running with the verbose flag `grunt <task> --verbose` is helpful when diagnosing things like this. What's the output when you run the task with the verbose flag?

Comment: Seems like it is missing the LHS of file mappings... strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've a configuration like the following, and it works fine for me.

```
    // uglify javascript
    uglify: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                mangle: true
            },
            files: {
                'js/dest.min.js': 'js/source.js'
            }
        }
    },
```

Probably you confused the destination with the source. Try to switch them.

Comment: Very stupid mistake, hard to spot when you work on something for too much time. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It were happening due to, you are not registering above given tasks.

OK, lets start with concatenation in grunt:

```
concat: {
    css: {
        src: ['./assets/css/*.css', './assets/css/**/*.css'],
        dest: './dist/css/style.css'
    },
    js: {
        src: ['./assets/js/*.js', './assets/js/**/*.js'],
        dest: './dist/js/script.js'
    }
},
```

so, this `concat` is supposed to collect all `css` files from above given `url / directories` and concatenate to given destination in one place and so with `js`.

this will be simple concatenated `style.css` and `script.js` at `dest` destination directory.

but it won't work, till you not register this `concat` task inside below line:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify']);
```

So, till `concat` will not concatenate those files in `dest` directory, how the `uglify` will collect and work!

Conclusion: task won't get execute till you not mention them inside `grunt.registerTask` function.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the path to my source file was incorrect. So it wasn't so much that the file is "empty" but that it can't be found.